# Enum in Grails Domain

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to use an `enum` in a Grails 2.1 domain class.  I'm generating the controller and views via the `grails generate-all <domain class>` command, and when I access the view I get the error shown below.  What am I missing here?

**Error**

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type 
com.domain.ActionEnum for property action; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 
[java.lang.String] to required type [com.domain.ActionEnum] for property action: 
no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

**Enum**    (in `/src/groovy`)

```
package com.domain

enum ActionEnum  {
    PRE_REGISTER(0), PURCHASE(2)

    private final int val
    public ActionEnum(int val) {
        this.val = val
    }

    int value() { return value }
}
```

**Domain**

```
package com.domain

class Stat {
    ActionEnum action

    static mapping = {
        version false
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<g:select name="action" 
    from="${com.domain.ActionEnum?.values()}"
    keys="${com.domain.ActionEnum.values()*.name()}" required="" 
    value="${xyzInstance?.action?.name()}"/>
```

---

**EDIT**

Now getting error `Property action must be a valid number` after changing the following.

**View**

```
<g:select optionKey='id' name="action" 
from="${com.domain.ActionEnum?.values()}" 
required="" 
value="${xyzInstance?.action}"/>  // I tried simply putting a number here
```

**Enum**

```
package com.domain

enum ActionEnum  {
    PRE_REGISTER(0), PURCHASE(2)

    final int id
    public ActionEnum(int id) {
        this.id = id
    }

    int value() { return value }

    static ActionEnum byId(int id) {
        values().find { it.id == id }
    } 
}
```

**Domain**

```
package com.domain.site

class Stat {
    static belongsTo = Game;

    Game game
    Integer action

    static mapping = {
        version false
   }

    static constraints = {
        action inList: ActionEnum.values()*.id
    }

    String toString() {
        return "${action}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look here ... 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748760/grails-enum-mapping

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969448/grails-gorm-enums

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Take a look here ...

[Grails Enum Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748760/grails-enum-mapping)

[Grails GORM & Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969448/grails-gorm-enums)

Also you may be hitting this as well.  From the docs:

1) Enum types are now mapped using their String value rather than the ordinal value. You can revert to the old behavior by changing your mapping as follows:

```
static mapping = {
    someEnum enumType:"ordinal"
}
```

Comment: +1 I had already seen the second link, but did not see the first.  I'm closer thanks to your help.  See question edits as I seem to be having a validation issue now.  Thanks!